# Android - is it possible to tell during runtime if the current device is an Amazon Kindle or NOOK from Barnes and Noble?

Tags: android, kindle, nook

I have an apk file that I upload to the Kindle store and the NOOK store (both reader tablets) and I have a place in the app where I would like to know whether the device is an Amazon device or from Barnes and Noble.  Is that possible? How do I find out this information during runtime?

Comment: Presumably data in `android.os.Build` will distinguish them, though I  don't have specific values handy.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect app is running on Kindle Fire](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309624/detect-app-is-running-on-kindle-fire)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nook color spec:
https://nookdeveloper.barnesandnoble.com/product/nook-color-specs.html

Contains the android.os.Build as mentioned by CommonsWare.

And the same for Kindle:
https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/fire/specifications.html

Anyhow, it seems better to use the android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER.
It will be 'Amazon' or not.

And its a duplicate of: [Detect app is running on Kindle Fire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309624/detect-app-is-running-on-kindle-fire)