# On Kindle fire IME_ACTION_DONE is not working

Tags: android, android-layout, kindle-fire

I have two editText's in layout , when I entered username soft keyboard shows "next" button and when i entered password soft keyboard shows "done".It is working properly in all devices except  " Kindle Fire " device.
On Kindle Fire , While entering password soft keyboard doesn't show "Done" button.
How can I show "Done" Button on kindle fire device? Is there any way to solve this issue ? 
Thanx in Advanced !!!

Comment: Put `android:imeActionId="actionDone"` in `<EditText />` password. Hope it works

Comment: android:imeActionId="actionDone" is not working

Comment: which Fire is this? the Gingerbread or the ICS one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the search , On Kindle fire, android:imeActionId="actionDone" doesn't support.You can detect the app is running on Kindle fire Device or not using  [Detect app is running on Kindle Fire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309624/detect-app-is-running-on-kindle-fire). and you can set android:imeActionId="actionGo" for it. For more information about Kindle fire devices ,you can see https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/fire/specifications.html.